# Replace words from an API in python

Tags: python

I am using an API I found online for one of my scripts, and I am wondering if I can change one word from the API to something else. My code is:

```py
import requests
people = requests.get('https://insult.mattbas.org/api/insult')

print("Welcome to the insult machine!\nType somebody you want to insult!")
b = input()

print(people.replace("You", b))
```

Is replace not a command? If so, what plugin and/or commands would I need to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The value returned from `requests.get` isn’t a string, it’s a `response` object and that class has no `replace` method.

Have a look at the structure of that class. For example, you can do `r = requests.get(...)` and `r.text.replace(...)`.

In other words, you need to operate on the text part of the response object.